# How to save Cloud Build Git tool builder output to a file

Tags: git, google-cloud-build

I am using Google Cloud Build with the git tool builder and trying to save the output of `git-diff` to a file. Then in a later step I want to `cat` the file. However, the file is always empty and I suspect `git-diff` isn't outputting any results.

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
    - -c
    - |
      git diff-tree --name-only --no-commit-id -r $SHORT_SHA > /workspace/files.txt
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args: 
    - -c
    - |
      echo "File contents " $(cat /workspace/files.txt)
```

Also, I tried running the step without using bash shell and still see no output in Cloud Build logs

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  args: ['diff-tree', '--name-only', '--no-commit-id', '-r', '$SHORT_SHA']
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I performed several tests and the output print the updated files in the commit. It works with long and short sha. Your cloud build command is correct (write the output and read it).

I don't know what you perform in your commit, it's more a git issue than a Cloud Build issue. Are you performing this on commit without file change, like pull request or merge/rebase?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out -- my issue was that I was accessing a private GitHub repository. I didn't realize this was the issue because there was no error message.

I tried following Google's documentation (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/access-private-github-repos) to use Cloud KMS with SSH tokens to access the private repo. However, I finally settled on creating a GitHub account for our deployment operations. Within that account, I created a personal token.

Then, I added the token as a trigger variable in Cloud Build. This enabled me to clone the repo and finally perform `git diff` inside Cloud Build.

Here's the final step:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  args: ['clone', 'https://${_TOKEN_}@github.com/[username]/[repo]']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
    - -c
    - |
      cd [repo] &&
      git diff-tree --name-only --no-commit-id -r $SHORT_SHA > /workspace/files.txt
```